# fetch message stanza in python

Tags: python, xmpp, quickblox

i am connecting quickblox with python and running it on console to recive all the messages. it did it correctly but now i want to extract some of its stanzas. the reciving stanza of message is in thi form.

```
<message to="11793378-35886@chat.quickblox.com/1220770403-quickblox-152081" from="35886_576e46bca0eb47decf000021@muc.chat.quickblox.com/12075843" id="577b97691f79407ba0685332" type="groupchat"><body>locationPARAM</body><markable xmlns="urn:xmpp:chat-markers:0" /><extraParams><message_id>577b97691f79407ba0685332</message_id><date>1467717481995</date><date_sent>1467717481</date_sent><rideId>10471740</rideId><lng>77.085653</lng><dialog_id>576e46bca0eb47decf000021</dialog_id><messageType>location</messageType><id>25393</id><name>Manoj Kumar</name><lat>28.4975462</lat><save_to_history>0</save_to_history></extraParams><delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" stamp="2016-07-05T11:18:03Z" /></message>
```

i want to extact extraparams contecnt from this message.
when i type
print msg['body']
it prints msg body
but print msg['extraParams']
didnt work. plzz help
i am using sleekxmpp

Comment: probably you have to parse extraParams, so probably you'll have to do something like msg['extraParams']['name']. I'm sorry but i don't know Python.

Comment: i have tried this already thnx

Comment: On quickstart I see some plugin registration such like:   xmpp.register_plugin('xep_0004') # Data Forms   I'd suggest to search something like that, maybe your extraParams are not automatically parsed by any component

Comment: yes extraParam are our not automatically parsed by component they are manuaaly inserted in stanza